# How to Iterate data from array inside another array in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have an array inside another array like this in php

```
Array
(
    [common_search] => Array
        (
            [BusinessName] => Sun Shine Vision
            [Address] => Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn
            [Phone] => 
        )

    [cache_table] => Array
        (
            [Details] => Speedtrax,Ample's Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,
        )

)
```

And i have to iterate these as seperate arrays in my result page using Jquery ,as  i want to get these arrays separately to display in different divs to set as html ,How can i get the data from two arrays (common_search , cache_table) separately . And in my html i want to set data like `$("#common_searchdiv").html(common_search)` and `$("#cache_tablediv").html(cache_table)` .  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When json-encoding named arrays they are going to be parsed as objects in javascript, so you can just do like this:

```
<script>
   var data = <?=json_encode($data);?>
</script>
```

since now data in javascript will be an object, so you can directly access properties like

```
<script>
data["common_search"]["BusinessName"];
</script>
```

or iterate over it with

`$.each`

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly pass data as array. Do json_encode of array. And then on jquery side parse the json and then run each/for loop. On the match of key you can add if condition.

Do something like this

```
var result = $.parseJSON(jsonstring);//jsonstring is your json encoded string.

for(var k in result) {
   if (k == 'common_search') {
       $("#common_searchdiv").html(result[k]); 

   } 
   if (k == 'cache_table') {
       $("#cache_tablediv").html(result[k]);
   }
}
```

For your reference it works

```
var jsonstring = {"common_search":{"strBusinessName":"Sun Shine Vision","strAddress":"Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn","intPhone":""},"cache_table":{"Details":"Speedtrax,Ample's Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,"}};
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(jsonstring).replace(/\'/, "/'");
var result = $.parseJSON(jsonstring);//jsonstring is your json encoded string.

for(var k in result) {

   if (k == 'common_search') {
       alert(result[k]['strBusinessName'])
       $("#common_searchdiv").html(result[k]['strBusinessName']); 

   } 
   if (k == 'cache_table') {
       $("#cache_tablediv").html(result[k]);
   }
}
```

Comment: After encoding data look like this : {"common_search":{"strBusinessName":"Sun Shine Vision","strAddress":"Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn","intPhone":""},"cache_table":{"Details":"Speedtrax,Ample's Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,"}}    But your code seems not working

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character ,  i think have to include json library in script ?

Comment: I think the problem is here Speedtrax,Ample's Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St you have Ample's the single qoutes is causing the problem can u escape it ?

Comment: Do this to replace it,       var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(jsonstring).replace(/\'/, "/'");

Comment: Okay go ahead let me know if any problem.

Comment: Now no errors ,but this doesnt working                            for (var k in jsonstring) { 
        if (k == 'common_search') {                                 $("#common_searchdiv").html(jsonstring[k]);

                                }

Comment: Why where is the problem. Tell me?

Comment: Did you used $.parseJson after escaping single character?

Comment: I have data like this :{"common_search":{"strBusinessName":"Sun Shine Vision","strAddress":"Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn","intPhone":""},"cache_table":{"Details":"Speedtrax,Ample's Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,"}} but i cant iterate through it to display in my divs

Comment: Try jsonstring[k]['strBusinessName'] instead of jsonstring[k]

Comment: Check my answer whic is updated mainly after for your reference i tried to run your code it works for me

Comment: Can you upvote and mark as tick if you feel it was helpful, so that future user can refer this answer

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
<?php
$arr_temp = Array
(
    'common_search' => Array
        (
            'BusinessName' => "Sun Shine Vision",
            'Address' => "Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn",
            'Phone' => ''
        ),

    'cache_table' => Array
        (
            'Details' => "Speedtrax,Ample's Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,"
        )

);

?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data_arr = <?php echo json_encode($arr_temp); ?>;

    $.each(data_arr,function(item){     
        $.each(data_arr[item],function(myitem){
            console.log(myitem);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How come <?php echo json_encode($arr_temp); ?>;
 used in javascript ?? its php code right

Comment: if you put this code in a php page inside script tag then it will work.